# Converting a XYZ Point cloud to a depth image

Tags: ros, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anyway to do the inverse of `depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz`. I need to do some conversions and calculation with pcl and convert information back to a depth image. I have the camera information as well

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304857/converting-a-xyz-point-cloud-to-a-depth-image/) by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-10-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Stefan,
Thanks did something like that. went reverse on whats being done in depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz algorithm.

```
if (cam_info_taken == true){
  sensor_msgs::CameraInfo info = cam_info;
  float centre_x = cam_info.K[2];
  float centre_y = cam_info.K[5];
  float focal_x = cam_info.K[0];
  float focal_y = cam_info.K[4];

  cv::Mat cv_image = cv::Mat(cam_info.height, cam_info.width, CV_32FC1,cv::Scalar(std::numeric_limits<float>::max()));

  for (int i=0; i<msg->points.size();i++){
    if (msg->points[i].z == msg->points[i].z){
        float z = msg->points[i].z*1000.0;
        float u = (msg->points[i].x*1000.0*focal_x) / z;
        float v = (msg->points[i].y*1000.0*focal_y) / z;
        int pixel_pos_x = (int)(u + centre_x);
        int pixel_pos_y = (int)(v + centre_y);

    if (pixel_pos_x > (cam_info.width-1)){
      pixel_pos_x = cam_info.width -1;
    }
    if (pixel_pos_y > (cam_info.height-1)){
      pixel_pos_y = cam_info.height-1;
    }
    cv_image.at<float>(pixel_pos_y,pixel_pos_x) = z;
    }       
  }
  
  cv_image.convertTo(cv_image,CV_16UC1);

  sensor_msgs::ImagePtr output_image = cv_bridge::CvImage(std_msgs::Header(), "16UC1", cv_image).toImageMsg();
  output_image->header = info.header;
  output_image->header.stamp = info.header.stamp = t;
  publish_result.publish(output_image);
  publish_cam_info.publish(info);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) with karma: 58 on 2018-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Haozhe Xie](https://answers.ros.org/users/53264/haozhe-xie/) on 2020-04-06**:
if (msg->points[i].z == msg->points[i].z) always returns true. Could you explain it?

**Comment by [Sagexs](https://answers.ros.org/users/26301/sagexs/) on 2020-10-16**:
... he checks the depth for nan value

According to the IEEE standard, NaN values have the odd property that comparisons involving them are always false.

**Comment by [AravindaDP](https://answers.ros.org/users/27826/aravindadp/) on 2020-11-01**:
Hi, did you implemented this as a standalone node or is bundled inside another component?

I'm also looking for the same functionality. it would be nice if you released this as a open source ros node.

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2020-11-01**:
Had this in a separate node

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use PCL's [RangeImagePlanar](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.8.1/classpcl_1_1_range_image_planar.html). Some example code for converting a PointCloud to a cv::Mat depth image can be found here: [to_cv_depth_img.h](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_cloud_image_proc/blob/master/pcl_to_cv_proc/include/pcl_to_cv_proc/to_cv_depth_img.h). This is perhaps not the most efficient option as it effectively does Z-buffer based rendering in software, but depending on application might be good enough.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2